# Does information entropy with binary options reduce to the simple frequency count?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, entropy

This is a simple question, but I'd like some reassurance that my thinking is correct:

I need to calculate Shannon information entropy and use it as a measure of randomness.
I have a sequence of 200 letters that consist of only say As and Bs.
In my case it's simple because the choice set is binary ($x_1$ and $x_2$, i.e. the information entropy equation $H(x) = -\sum_{i=1}^np(x_i) \log_2 p(x_i)$ becomes:

$$
H(x) = -(p(x_1)*log_2(p(x_1))+(1-p(x_1))*log_2(1-p(x_1)))
$$

So for example, if I have a sequence of `150 As and 50 Bs`, then H(x)= 0.8, for `100 As and 100 Bs`, H=1, so maximum surprise and for `0 As and 200 Bs`, H(x) is taken to be = 0, no surprise at all.

I will be using this entropy value in a statistical analysis as a dependent variable. It occurred to me that it might be overkill to calculate H(x) if I could just as well just take the frequency of e.g. the letter since it's a binary case?

I'm wondering if in my case the entropy formulation gives me any additional information that I wouldn't have gotten from just looking at the frequency count of one of the letters.
In other words, knowing that A occured 150 out of 200 times is enough because it is identical to knowing that H(x) = 0.8

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but since you can deduce entropy from frequency, then it's information is contained in the frequencies. This does not mean the entropy is not useful for analysis. If you know that $H(x)=0.8$, then either $A$ happened $150$ or $50$, this is the information you lose.

Comment: Ah yes indeed I forgot to mention that it doesn't matter for me if it's A that has happened 150 times or B, because they are irrelevant. I assume from this it follows that the frequency count information is fully contained in the entropy formulation

Comment: If the label don't matter then $H(x)$ is a sufficient statistic of the set $\{ p(x_1),p(x_2) \}$. This is true only for binary alphabet.

Comment: Thank you! How can I flag this question as answered?

Comment: There needs to be an answer for you to accept one. I think it is perfectly fine to leave the question like that.